# Avoid Auto Open When clicking in Kendo Multi Select

Tags: kendo-ui

How to disable auto open when clicking the kendo multiselect auto complete box.It may be open when i start typing.

Comment: Providing some code of what you already have is useful. For example, how have you configured your multiselect to be autocomplete?

Answer (score 3):

You should intercept `open` event, check for length of typed text and if it is `0` then invoke `preventDefault`. Something like:

```js
$("#required").kendoMultiSelect({
  open : function (e) {
    var len = this.input.val().length;
    if (len == 0) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<select id="required" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select attendees...">
  <option>Steven White</option>
  <option>Nancy King</option>
  <option>Nancy Davolio</option>
  <option>Robert Davolio</option>
  <option>Michael Leverling</option>
  <option>Andrew Callahan</option>
  <option>Michael Suyama</option>
  <option selected>Anne King</option>
  <option>Laura Peacock</option>
  <option>Robert Fuller</option>
  <option>Janet White</option>
  <option>Nancy Leverling</option>
  <option>Robert Buchanan</option>
  <option>Margaret Buchanan</option>
  <option selected>Andrew Fuller</option>
  <option>Anne Davolio</option>
  <option>Andrew Suyama</option>
  <option>Nige Buchanan</option>
  <option>Laura Fuller</option>
</select>
```